# How to display the label of a select option?

Tags: jquery, select

I have the following script written:

http://jsfiddle.net/rgf8K/

The way it works, is that you select you Birth Month and favorite color, and then it should provide you with your "Celebrity Name."

Right now the way the script is written is wrong... because the output does not display the option label for the selected option value. If the person selects January for month and Green for color, I want the output to say: Your celebrity name is Linda Green.

How can I display the label of the selected label option instead? Thanks so much!!

HTML

```
<form>
    <select id="month">
        <option value="">- birth month -</option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
    </select>  
    <label class="January" for="January">Linda</label>
    <label class="February" for="February">Chris</label>
    <label class="March" for="March">James</label>


    <select id="color">
        <option value="">- favorite color -</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
    </select>  
    <label class="Green" for="Green">Roberts</label>
    <label class="Blue" for="Blue">Blue</label>
    <label class="Red" for="Red">Unger</label>
</form>

    <p id="output"></p>
```

jQuery

```
$("#month, #color").change(function () {
    var month = $("#month").val();
    var color = $("#color").val();
    var content = '';
    if (month && color) {
        content = 'Your celebrity name is ' + month + ' name ' + color + ' name';
    }
    $("#output").text(content).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen labels used like that before.

Comment: This should be a matter of selecting the correct label in the DOM based on the color selected. Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: use an array instead of the strange label system you have

Comment: Thanks... Haven't figured out exactly how to solve this... would greatly appreciate any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value attributes of your options:

```
<select id="month">
        <option value="">- birth month -</option>
        <option value="Linda">January</option>
        <option value="Chris">February</option>
        <option value="James">March</option>
    </select>
```

Likewise for the colors.

```
<select id="color">
        <option value="">- favorite color -</option>
        <option value="Roberts">Green</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Unger">Red</option>
    </select>
```

Then remove the labels and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

since you have the class name for the value of the month select you can try this:

change:

```
var month = $("#month").val();
var color =$("#color").val();
```

to:

```
var month = $('.'+$("#month").val()).text();
var color = $('.'+$("#color").val()).text();
```